# Does every smooth unit-speed curve in $\Bbb R^3$ have a well defined torsion? Explain.

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

The torsion at $\gamma(s)$ for a unit-speed curve $\gamma$ in $\Bbb R^3$ is the value   $\tau \in\Bbb R$ such that $\textbf{b'(s)}= -\tau(s)\textbf{n(s)}$ where $\textbf{b(s)}=\textbf{t(s)}\times\textbf{n(s)}$ is the binormal vector of $\gamma$ at $\gamma(s)$ and $\textbf{n(s)}= \frac{1}{k(s)}\textbf{t'(s)}$ is the principal normal vector of $\gamma$ at $\gamma(s)$ with curvature $k(s)$.

I understand the torsion will not be defined unless our curvature $k(s)$ doesn't equal zero, however I'm not sure how to word it in a mathematical proof/explanation of a sort.

Comment: You have pretty much proved it. A curve $\gamma$ in $ \mathbb{R}^3$ has well-defined torsion iff it has non-vanishing curvature. There isn't really anything else to prove.

Comment: To make your answer absolutely clear, you could provide an example of a smooth unit-speed curve which does not have well-defined torsion.